# Array key of string always evaluates to first character (true)

Tags: php

When:

```
$person = array('name' => 'bill');
```

`isset($person['jibberish'])` evaluates to FALSE.

But:

```
$person = 'bill';
```

`isset($person['jibberish'])` evaluates to TRUE, as `$person['jibberish']` returns the first character of string $person.

Is this as intended? This came as a shocker to me today, as I've always used `empty($array['key'])` without ever including `is_array()` in my if statements.

Comment: This is a good example of the not-100%-obvious behaviour of PHP string->int type casting. Try `$person = 'bill'; var_dump(isset($person['10 green bottles']));` - see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr for the key to why you see this behaviour. The thing you need to remember is that you are dealing with C strings underneath, so everything is really just a byte array.

Comment: Any string that begins with a numeric will become that number when type cast to int, so (int)'10 green bottles' == 10; // true.  If it doesn't start with a numeric, it will be cast to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$person` is a string, the array-like-index is converted to an `int`.

```
(int)'any non-numeric string in the world' == 0
```

So, you "naturally" get the first character of any string if you use a random, non-numeric string as the index.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you are printing the undefined index of the string, not array.
If you try to print indexes of strings in PHP, you'll have the each character of the string:

```
$person = 'bill';
$person[0] //b
$person[1] //i
$person[2] //l
$person[3] //l
```